# How to use scanner to add data dynamically in a collection

Tags: java, collections, java.util.scanner

Help me to scan name and age from the user instead of predefining it in the ArrayList.

I have initialised name and age in the following program help me to scan the name and age from the user and it should compare then it should sort using collection.

```
public class Control {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();
        Student stu1 = new Student(22, "Gokul");
        Student stu2 = new Student(12, "Dolby");
        Student stu3 = new Student(24, "Rahul");
        Student stu4 = new Student(56, "Raj");

        studs.add(stu1);
        studs.add(stu2);
        studs.add(stu3);
        studs.add(stu4);

        Collections.sort(studs,new StudAge());
        for(Student stud : studs) {
            System.out.println(stud);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: you would use it like you would in any other flow.

Comment: I can't get you..

Comment: whether you use a Scanner during sorting, or in just a "read name - print name" program, the way you use it is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
public class Control {

    private static Scanner sc; //Making sc as a field variable so that we no longer need to explicitly close the resource 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your data ");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();
    Student stu1 = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine()); //Dynamically asking user to input age and name

    System.out.println("Please enter the Age and Name of the first user : ");
    Student stu2 = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Please enter the Age and Name of the second user : ");
    Student stu3 = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Please enter the Age and Name of the third user : ");
    Student stu4 = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine());

    studs.add(stu1);
    studs.add(stu2);
    studs.add(stu3);
    studs.add(stu4);

    Collections.sort(studs, new StudAge());
    for (Student stud : studs) {
        System.out.println(stud);
    }

}
```

> There are still ways to optimize this, but if using `scanner` to take **Dynamic Input** from user is your only goal, then, this will do the trick.

Here is the tailor made code for you.

```
public class Control {

    private static Scanner sc; //Making sc as a field variable so that we no longer need to explicitly close the resource 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your data \n\n\n");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();

        // Asking the user to enter number of records he/she wishes to enter
        System.out.println("How many records would you like to enter : ");

        for (int i = sc.nextInt(); i > 0; i--) {

            System.out.println("Please enter the Name : "); //Asking user for the name
            String name = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Please enter the age of " + name + " :");  //Asking user for the age of that specific name
            int age = sc.nextInt();

            studs.add(new Student(age, name));
        }

        Collections.sort(studs, new StudAge());
        for (Student stud : studs) {
            System.out.println(stud);
        }

    }

}
```

> This last code is memory efficient as it saves you the space of creating multiple number of reference variables and then `add` them to the `List`. Instead we directly **create** and **pass** the object inside the `add` method of the `List` along with its parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot dood :)

Comment: No problem, up vote too pls :)
also, look how to optimize it as well, That will save u soo much memory and processing time

Comment: I need scanner to ask like Enter your name: then enter your age: for 3 user then it should print.

Comment: Dood it should ask for name separately and age separately for length of 3 times like.   for (int I=0;i<3;i++); it should as the name and age separately for three times if  I < 3 if we change to 4 then 4 times like that I am trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

This is simple program to add as many students as You want, also as You define ArrayList there is no need to use any Comparator because ArrayList has automatic sort by natural order like(1,3,5,8) or ('A','B','C').

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("How many students You want to add: ");
    int numberOfStudents = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); //to consume /n
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter age: ");
        int age = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); //to consume/n
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        studs.add(age, name);
    }
    //You don`t need to sort cuz it is ArrayList and elements inside are automatically sorted by natural order
    for(Student stud : studs) {
        System.out.println(stud);
    }
}
```

}

And if u realy want to use Comparator there is a code:

1st You need to create class which will do the sort

```
public class AgeComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

@Override
public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
    if(s1.getAge() > s2.getAge())
        return 1;
    else if(s1.getAge() == s2.getAge())
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

}

And in your main class add:

```
AgeComparator ageComparator = new AgeComparator();
Collections.sort(studs, ageComparator);
```

Comment: I guess im to late ;d

Comment: I am getting error in studs.add(age, name); line its showing - The method add(int, Student) in the type List<Student> is not applicable for the arguments (int, String).

Comment: I fixed it dood :)

Comment: The problem was propably on class Student. I bet u have in different order (String, int) :)

Comment: dood but it is not sorting in order

Comment: I want to compare the age using Comparator

Comment: 1st thing u can do is to write "Collections.sort(studs);" after 1st loop and 2nd as u mention Comparator i will edit the code bellow so u can see how it looks.

Comment: Thanks dood then for name comparator instead of getAge I replace with getName its giving me a error.

Comment: For names u need to implemet Comparable in Student class "public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
" and override method compareTo and after You can add new Comparator and make "public int compare(Student p1, Student p2) {
   return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
package sys;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Control {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Student> studs = new ArrayList<Student>();
        System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter age and name :");
            Student stu1 = new Student(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextLine());
            studs.add(stu1);
        }
        Collections.sort(studs, new StudAge());

        for (Student stud : studs) {
            System.out.println(stud);
        }

    }

}
```